# Swift DateComponentsFormatter drop leading zeroes but keep at least one digit in Minutes place

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I am using the following DateComponentsFormatter in Swift:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle   = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [.default]
```

This produces results like 2:41 (for 2 minutes and 41 seconds) and 08 (for 8 seconds). I would, however, like to keep at least one digit in the Minutes place, returning 0:08 instead of 08. Is this possible with the DateComponentsFormatter? I would prefer a solution that returns a localized result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. This can be easily accomplished adding a ternary conditional based on the time interval when setting the date components formatter allowed units:

---

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Formatter {
    static let positional: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let positional = DateComponentsFormatter()
        positional.unitsStyle = .positional
        positional.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return positional
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension TimeInterval {
    var positionalTime: String {
        Formatter.positional.allowedUnits = self >= 3600 ?
                                            [.hour, .minute, .second] :
                                            [.minute, .second]
        let string = Formatter.positional.string(from: self)!
        return string.hasPrefix("0") && string.count > 4 ?
            .init(string.dropFirst()) : string
    }
}
```

---

Usage

```
8.0.positionalTime     //    "0:08"
161.0.positionalTime   //    "2:41"
3600.0.positionalTime  // "1:00:00"
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @jhk I will check it

Comment: weird it returns "01:00:00" instead of "1:00:00"

Comment: Yeah - I was going crazy until I looked at old screenshots of the app!

Comment: I think you will have to manually deal with it if you don't want that leading zero

Comment: Beware that dodifying the static Formatter.positional is not thread safe. If this matters, either create the DateComponentsFormatter every time, or have two statics: Formatter.positionalHHMMSS and Formatter.positionalMMSS.

Comment: @SimonPickup sure but it is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an appropriate positional time string by modifying the `allowedUnits` and `zeroFormattingBehavior` based on the duration. Note that this will pad two leading zeros for minutes when it's desirable to only have one, so that case is handled afterwards in a safe manner.

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
if duration < 60 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad //pad seconds and minutes ie 00:05
} else if duration >= 60*60 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
}

var formattedDuration = formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "0"
if formattedDuration.hasPrefix("00") {
    formattedDuration = String(formattedDuration.dropFirst()) //remove leading 0 ie 0:05
}
```

Here's a list of `duration`s and `formattedDuration`s:

```
0 ▶️ 0:00
5 ▶️ 0:05
30 ▶️ 0:30
60 ▶️ 1:00
65 ▶️ 1:05
3600 ▶️ 1:00:00
3665 ▶️ 1:00:05
3660 ▶️ 1:01:00
```

**Alternate Solution**

You can achieve the same result without checking for two leading zeros by utilizing the `.dropTrailing` `zeroFormattingBehavior`, interestingly enough. I will caution I don't understand exactly why this works and do not know what impact it may have on localization. Note that if duration is `0`, the result is `"0"`, so we can use `.pad` in this case to get a result of `"00:00"` instead. With that you end up in the same situation noted above but maybe you will feel that is an edge case that may not need handling.

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
if duration >= 60 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .default
} else if duration == 0 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    //is 00:00 but should be 0:00
} else {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropTrailing //magic here
}
let formattedDuration = formatter.string(from: duration) ?? "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Came up with this solution, employing a regex, that seemingly covers all cases:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

func durationString(for duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
    formatter.string(from: duration)!
        .replacingOccurrences(of: #"^00[:.]0?|^0"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
}

durationString(for: 0)      // 0:00
durationString(for: 1)      // 0:01
durationString(for: 10)     // 0:10
durationString(for: 60)     // 1:00
durationString(for: 600)    // 10:00
durationString(for: 3600)   // 1:00:00
durationString(for: 36000)  // 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out a different zeroFormattingBehavior property value. I use this to get the result I think you're seeking, but experiment as necessary...

```
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [.pad]
```

Comment: This would display the hours as well `"0:00:08"` instead of `"0:08"`. And even if you set the DateComponentsFormatter maximumUnitCount property to 2 won't solve the issue when using positional unit style.