# Converting CMTime To String is wrong value return

Tags: swift, string, cmtime

I want `CMTime` to String an human readable.
So I Found below code.

```
extension CMTime {

    var durationText:String {
        let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self)
        let hours:Int = Int(totalSeconds / 3600)
        let minutes:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
        let seconds:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

        if hours > 0 {
            return String(format: "%i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
        } else {
            return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
        }
    }

}
```

And I Have `30 second` video files. It's `CMTime` value is `17945`.
I expect this durationText `00:30`.
But result is `00:29`.
And other video files same.
What Should I fix??

Comment: Your durationText extension returns `00:30` for me. when I run `CMTime(value: 30, timescale: 1).durationText`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641797/2303865

Comment: Just some notes. You can use CMTime instance property `seconds`. No need to create a variable for that. `let hours = Int(seconds / 3600)`. Btw Swift is a type inferred language. No need to explicitly set the type to Int.

Comment: `extension CMTime {
    var hrs:  Int { return Int(seconds / 3600) }
    var mins: Int { return Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60) }
    var secs: Int { return Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)) }
    var duration: String {
        return hrs > 0 ?
            String(format: "%i:%02i:%02i", hrs, mins, secs) :
            String(format:    "%02i:%02i",      mins, secs)
    }
}` `CMTime(value: 30, timescale: 1).duration`
`

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried CMTime value is 17945. and timescale is 600

Comment: Why don't you work with timescale 1?

Comment: the result is correct 18000 should return 30

Comment: I do not init CMTime. It's just my video file's duration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47585714/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried your past answer. but It's just print out `0m 29s`

Comment: You video duration is less than 30s. the duration is `29.90833333333333` what would you expect? Round up the result yourself if you need it. `seconds.rounded(.up)`

Comment: @LeoDabus No...In Xcode, this video file's duration is 30s. and Finder QuickTime Player also 30s. But why In my app 29s???

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah...Okay I See. I understand

Comment: probably better to use the standard `rounded()` which uses `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` rounding rule.

Comment: @LeoDabus So much thankyou. I fixed it. You just answer anything. I select your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to round your seconds before calculating your time components.

```
extension CMTime {
    var roundedSeconds: TimeInterval {
        return seconds.rounded()
    }
    var hours:  Int { return Int(roundedSeconds / 3600) }
    var minute: Int { return Int(roundedSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60) }
    var second: Int { return Int(roundedSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)) }
    var positionalTime: String {
        return hours > 0 ?
            String(format: "%d:%02d:%02d",
                   hours, minute, second) :
            String(format: "%02d:%02d",
                   minute, second)
    }
}
```

---

Testing all the possible edge rounding cases:

```
CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 600).positionalTime              // "00:00"
CMTime(value: 300, timescale: 600).positionalTime            // "00:01"
CMTime(value: 600, timescale: 600).positionalTime            // "00:01"

CMTime(value: 18000 - 600, timescale: 600).positionalTime      // "00:29"
CMTime(value: 17945, timescale: 600).positionalTime            // "00:30"
CMTime(value: 18000, timescale: 600).positionalTime            // "00:30"
CMTime(value: 18055, timescale: 600).positionalTime            // "00:30"
CMTime(value: 18000 + 600, timescale: 600).positionalTime      // "00:31"


CMTime(value: 2160000 - 600, timescale: 600).positionalTime  // "59:59"
CMTime(value: 2160000 - 300, timescale: 600).positionalTime  // "1:00:00"
CMTime(value: 2160000, timescale: 600).positionalTime        // "1:00:00"
```